# Why are Duals of Two Equivalent compound propositions Equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, duality-theorems

I know that if we have two equivalent propositions p and q then p* and q* will also be equivalent where p* and q* are duals of p and q respectively. I am looking for some explanation to why duals of equivalent propositions also equivalent?
Reference
Discrete Mathematics by K.H Rosen 7th edition
Exercise 1.3 question no 39

> Why are the duals of two equivalent compound propositions also
>   equivalent, where these compound propositions contain only the
>   operators ∧,∨, and ¬?

Regards

Comment: I'm not really sure where to start or what tools to use to solve this. This is in chapter $1$ of a $2000$ level discrete math book, so we haven't been introduced to induction or any other proof techniques. I tried drawing up logic tables for some propositions and their duals, and found that if a proposition s is true in $x$ instances and false in $y$ instances (where $x+y$ is of course a power of $2$), then $s^{*}$ is false in $x$ instances and true in $y$ instances

Answer (score 4):

Let us start by reconsidering the definition of the dual $\phi^*$ for a given propositional formula $\phi$. It can be summarised by the correspondences:
\begin{align}
\phi \land \psi &\overset*\iff\phi \lor \psi\\
\mathbf F &\overset*\iff \mathbf T
\end{align}

We reuse a fundamental idea of the earlier exercises in the mentioned chapter, namely that $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ precisely when $\phi$ and $\psi$ are satisfied by exactly the same lines in a truth table.

> **Observation 1**: A line of a truth table is nothing more than a function $v$ which assigns to each propositional variable a value $\mathbf T$ or $\mathbf F$ and subsequently evaluates the definitions of the connectives for this assignment.

Such a $v$ is known in the literature as a *valuation* or a *boolean interpretation*. Abstracting this notion away from the intuitive use in truth tables is a big asset in proving generic theorems. This is because it allows us to discuss rigorously an "arbitrary line of a truth table".

For example, by considering the two possibilities $v(p)=\mathbf T$ and $v(p)=\mathbf F$, it is not hard to see that $v(p\lor \neg p)= \mathbf T$ for every valuation of $\{p\}$. Similarly one can show that $v(p\to q) = v(\neg p \lor q)$ for each valuation of $\{p,q\}$, thus proving equivalence of these statements.

> **Observation 2**: $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent precisely when $v(\phi) =v(\psi)$ for all valuations $v$.

We need one final ingredient before turning to the main result.

> **Definition**: Given a valuation $v$, the valuation $v^*$ is defined by: $$v^*(p) = \begin{cases}\mathbf T&\text{ if $v(p) = F$}\\\mathbf F&\text{ if $v(p) = T$}\end{cases}$$

The desired result will follow from the following:

> **Theorem**: For any formula $\phi$ and valuation $v$, we have: $$v(\phi^*) = v^*(\neg\phi)$$

By assumption $\phi$ will have one of the following forms:

- $\phi = p$
- $\phi = \mathbf F$
- $\phi = \mathbf T$
- $\phi = \neg \tau$
- $\phi = \tau \lor \tau'$
- $\phi = \tau \land \tau'$

I will only prove the assertion for the last possibility $\tau \land \tau'$; the other options are similar or easier. We assume that the result has been proven for $\tau$ and $\tau'$.

Note that this decomposition of $\phi$ into possible forms is known formally as *structural induction*; it allows us to reason about an arbitrary formula in a structural manner, similar to proving an implication like $(\phi \lor \psi)\to \tau$: we first assume $\phi$ and show $\tau$ from it, and then do the same for $\psi$.

Now for the proof:

\begin{align}
v(\phi^*) &= v((\tau\land\tau')^*)\\
&= v(\tau^* \lor \tau'^*)\\
&= f^\lor(v(\tau^*),v(\tau'^*))\\
&= f^\lor(~v^*(\neg\tau),v^*(\neg\tau')~)\\
&= v^*(\neg \tau \lor \neg\tau')\\
&= v^*(\neg(\tau\land\tau'))\\
&= v^*(\neg\phi)
\end{align}

where $f^\lor$ denotes the definition of $\lor$ in terms of truth values (so $f^\lor(\mathbf F,\mathbf F) = \mathbf F$, otherwise $f^\lor$ yields $\mathbf T$). In the second-to-last step, a De Morgan equivalence is used.

---

Intuitively, the above result states that for every line of a truth table for $\phi^*$, we can mechanically construct one with the same value for $\neg\phi$. Because $\neg\phi$ and $\neg\psi$ are also equivalent, this means that the constructed valuations agree on $\neg\phi$ and $\neg\psi$. Additionally, it is not hard to see that every valuation on $\neg\phi$ can be constructed in this way, and we can transform them back to valuations of $\phi^*$ since $v^{**}=v$. These ingredients together establish equivalence of $\phi^*$ and $\psi^*$.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are Duals of Two Equivalent compound propositions Equivalent?

Let $p$ and $q$ be equivalent
compound propositions involving only the operators $\wedge$,
$\vee$, $\neg$, $T$ and $F$. Note that $\neg p$ and $\neg q$ are also equivalent.
Use De Morgan’s laws as many times as necessary to
push negations in as far as possible within these compound
propositions, changing $\vee$s to $\wedge$s, and vice versa, and changing
$T$s to $F$s, and vice versa. This shows that $\neg p$ and $\neg q$ are
the same as $p^*$ and $q^*$ except that each atomic proposition
pi within them is replaced by its negation. From this, we can
conclude that $p^*$ and $q^*$ are equivalent because $\neg p$ and $\neg q$ are.

> Reference
>
> [Discrete Mathematics](http://www2.fiit.stuba.sk/%7Ekvasnicka/Mathematics%20for%20Informatics/Rosen_Discrete_Mathematics_and_Its_Applications_7th_Edition.pdf) by K.H Rosen 7th edition
>
> Exercise 1.3 question no 39